# Extjs4 tabpanel, disable all child item without looping them

Tags: extjs, tabs, extjs4, tabpanel

is there are any way to disable all child items on Extjs4 tab panel, without looping them.

my code:

```
var myPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
    region: 'east',
    title: 'my panel title',
    width: 200,
    id: 'my-panel',
    split: true,
    collapsible: true,
    collapsed: true,
    floatable: true,
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    items: [
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        id: 'my-detail-panel',
        title: 'My Info',
        autoScroll: true,
        file: false,
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch',
        tpl: myDetailsTpl
    }),
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        id: 'my-more-detail-panel',
        title: 'My more info',
        autoScroll: true,
        file: false,
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch',
        tpl: myMoreDetailsTpl
    })
            ]
});
```

i need disable myPanel's all child items, but still need to 'myPanel' keep status as enable .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myPanel.items.each(function(c){c.disable();})
```

then

```
myPanel.items.each(function(c){c.enable();})
```

to fire them back up again.

This *is* looping, but it is not using a "for loop" as I think the question was meant to state.

Comment: wait what? How is iterating not looping? :) The real answer here is NO there is not a disableAll function but obviously you can write one like Geronimo has shown.

Comment: +1 Your right @DmitryB, I just assumed he meant without using a "for each" loop or something. I didn't know if anyone would catch that, so I wrote the question at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can just set disabled:true on the initial config for each panel. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: No ,what I need is dynamically enable or disable all items in tabpanel.

Answer (score 0):

Try his:

```html
// Create your own property for storing statu, 

config{
  allMyTabItemsEnabled = true;
}

// Then on all the items you want to disable/enable, add:

bind: {
  disabled: '{!allMyTabItemsEnabled }'
}
```